# Free program to show how steady my network connection is

Tags: gratis, networking, network-monitor

I recently signed a new contract with my ISP. They agreed to upgrade my network connection. The connection speed, as they told me, would increase at least two times. They also told me that my modem was too old, and they would replace it with a new one. When the new setup was done, I could see that my network connection became faster. It used to took 5 seconds before I could reach YouTube, now it only took me 2 seconds. While I was happy and enjoyed watching the videos on YouTube, however, I found that my network connection was not stable, and my computer was getting disconnected from the Internet every several minutes. I talked to my ISP about this problem, but they wanted me to prove that the problem was caused by their defective modem. The problem persists, but I have no idea how to show them the truth.
So, I am wondering if there are any free program to help me out. I mean, I need a free program to show graphic about my network connection against time when I connect to YouTube.

Please help if you can!
Thank you!

Comment: What operating system should it run on?

Comment: @Undo. Mine is XP SP3

Comment: You might want to check this out, maybe it will help:  http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/310/what-software-can-i-use-to-monitor-the-quality-of-my-internet-connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [Ping Plotter](http://www.pingplotter.com/), which will show you lag, buffering issues, client complaints slow load and most importantly **dropped connections**. They are offering trial version for a month so i guess you can download the demo version for your stated purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ping` to keep track of your network connection:

```
C:\> ping -t -l 1024 yahoo.com

Pinging yahoo.com [206.190.36.45] with 1024 bytes of data:
Reply from 206.190.36.45: bytes=1024 time=98ms TTL=44
Reply from 206.190.36.45: bytes=1024 time=109ms TTL=44
Reply from 206.190.36.45: bytes=1024 time=107ms TTL=44
Reply from 206.190.36.45: bytes=1024 time=103ms TTL=44
Reply from 206.190.36.45: bytes=1024 time=105ms TTL=44
Reply from 206.190.36.45: bytes=1024 time=111ms TTL=44
Reply from 206.190.36.45: bytes=1024 time=104ms TTL=44
Reply from 206.190.36.45: bytes=1024 time=111ms TTL=44
```